# SQL copy row with a new ID after change happens

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello i have a SQL Table which look like this:

```
ID      BEZEICHNUNG  PREIS        UPDATE_DATE          FLAG

1       Drake        Room         14.06.2012 16:00     0
2       Blazer       BS           12.05.2012 14:45     0
```

when i change a value i want to copy the row with a new id and change the flag to 1 
it should look like this:

```
ID      BEZEICHNUNG  PREIS        UPDATE_DATE          FLAG

1       Drake        Room         11.07.2012 09:40     1
2       Blazer       BS           12.05.2012 14:45     0
3       Dune         Room         11.07.2012 09:40     0
```

when i change the row the update_date updates itself and set a flag to 1.
how can i create an sql statement like this.

the current trigger look like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDT_DIENSTLEISTUNG]
   ON [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

   SET  NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE DIENSTLEISTUNG
      SET UPDATE_DATE    = getdate ()
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                   FROM inserted);


END;
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: it's an MS SQL Server 2008 on a server

Comment: i dont have an sql statement yet.

Comment: Then how are you updating the update_TIMESTAMP column ?

Comment: sorry i'll look at it. i'll post the sql statement

Comment: If there's a subsequent update to `ID` 3, do we leave the `ID` 1 row alone at that time? If so, how do you later correlate the `ID` 1 row with anything (all of its column values are different from the row at `ID` 3 at this point)? If yes, the only column I can see that we can match between the two rows is the `update_timestamp` - so what if more than one row is updated at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please create this trigger first and then try to update the table

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDT_DIENSTLEISTUNG]
   ON [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG]
   AFTER  UPDATE
AS

BEGIN
 SET  NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @MAX_ID INT;
SELECT @MAX_ID=MAX(ID) FROM DIENSTLEISTUNG;

declare @tmp Table(ID  int,     BEZEICHNUNG varchar(20), PREIS varchar(20),
     UPDATE_DATE datetime,      FLAG bit)

insert into @tmp
select ID,BEZEICHNUNG,PREIS,UPDATE_DATE,1 [flag] from deleted;

delete T from DIENSTLEISTUNG T JOIN @tmp I
ON T.ID=I.ID

INSERT INTO DIENSTLEISTUNG
SELECT @MAX_ID+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) [ID],BEZEICHNUNG,PREIS,GETDATE(),0 
FROM INSERTED

INSERT INTO DIENSTLEISTUNG
select * from @tmp


 SET  NOCOUNT OFF;
END;
```

Comment: For a multi-row update, that will generate multiple rows with the same `ID` value (all of the newly inserted ones will use the same `@max_id+1` value)

Comment: hello joe. i tried your solution but there is something missing. i updated my post. please could you look at it again?

Answer (score -1):

One option to do that (original row is updated, but history row is inserted) is to use SQL similar to this:

```
create table MyTab
(
    [id] int primary key identity,
    [name] varchar(50),
    [type] varchar(50),
    [flag] bit default 0
)

insert into MyTab([name], [type])
    Values('Drake', 'Room')
insert into MyTab([name], [type])
    Values('Blazer', 'BS')

select * from myTab

Update MyTab
    Set name = name + 'new'
Output deleted.name, deleted.type, 1
into myTab(name, type, flag)
Where name = 'Drake'

select * from myTab
```